# Error refreshing materialized view from a stored procedure (not a valid month)

Tags: c#, sql, plsql, entity-framework-4

I am trying to refresh a materialized view from a stored procedure, I command to call the procedure from csharp but when refreshing the view it sends me the error: ORA-12008: error in materialized view refresh path, followed by: ORA-01843: not a valid month, I've tried it with another view and yes it's refreshing, any help for this detail?

attached image

[image]

This is my code:

I am not passing parameters and neither dates, I am just trying to refresh the view from C # visual studio

```
  string oradb = "Data Source=DATA; User Id=DATA; Password=DATA;";
            OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb);
            conn.Open();
            OracleCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "ACTUALIZA_VISTAS_VRE";
            //cmd.CommandText = "exec REFRESH_RECUPERADO";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
```

Comment: how are you passing the Date.. ? can you show us that..? also what is the expected format of the Oracle date in your database..? are you passing it by mm/dd/yyyy` or `DD-MON-YYYY` please show as much code as possible that relates to your current issue and or question ..

Comment: @DanyMartinez_ Please update the question with this code in a formatted block. Also, I'm not seeing a date in there. Where is the date coming from exactly?

Comment: I edited and added the code.

Comment: I am not passing dates as parameters, I just try to update a view using a stored procedure.

Comment: The SQL within the MV must be attempting a date conversion. Some value in the source data is not in the expected format.

Comment: Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stored procedure or materialized view is where the code is that is providing the invalid month. Is ACTUALIZA_VISTAS_VRE calling REFRESH_RECUPERADO?